# Find the area of the region enclosed by the curves $y = \tan(x)$, $y = -3\tan(x)$ and $x = \pi/4$

Tags: calculus, integration, area

Find the area enclosed by the curves $y = \tan(x)$, $y = -3\tan(x)$ and $x = \pi/4$.

What can possibly be the area, $\tan(x)$ and $-3\tan(x)$ never intersect unless it is $\frac{\pi}{2}k$. There is no upper bound to find because the two curve goes to different direction, so confused about this question.

Comment: Are you not aware that tan(0)= 0?  The two curves certainly do intersect at (0, 0)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

The integral you are interested in can be written as
\begin{align*}
I = \int_{0}^{\pi/4}(\tan(x) - (-3\tan(x)))\mathrm{d}x = \int_{0}^{\pi/4}4\tan(x)\mathrm{d}x
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

$$\int\limits_{x=0}^{\pi/4} 4 \tan (x)\ dx = \log 4 \approx 1.38629$$